# Command `yum history package-list` not finding expected matches

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

On a server of Red Hat 7.9 (Maipo), we got an estimate that we removed the [DSMC application](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/TSM+for+Linux+-+Install%2C+Configure%2C+Set+Up%2C+and+Confirm+the+Scheduler) from about five months ago. As a due diligence, we need to find more details including exactly when and who.

The application got involved in an alert of `dsmc killed by SIGABRT` timed five months ago, so the YUM Erase (`E`) action must be within the last five months. However, the system logs are gone with rotation, so we are limited to the `yum history`.

We also knew that the RPMs should be `TIVsm-API64.x86_64.rpm` and `TIVsm-BA.x86_64.rpm`, so we searched by the command `yum history package-list TIVsm\*`, in which `\*` is the wildcard. However, it did not get any match.

In addition, we also listed all the YUM transactions by `yum history list all` and look into all the recent transactions with `E` actions, e.g., `yum history info <ID>`, but still no match.

**Miscellaneous:**

We confirmed the below packages exist by command `yum list installed gsk*`. However, `yum history package-list gsk\*` still returns no match.

```
gskcrypt64-8.0-50.78.x86_64
gskssl64-8.0-50.78.x86_64
```

We also checked `yum list all | grep -i "TIV"`, and got no match either. Therefore, we suspect the DSMC application was not installed through the YUM channel in the first place. However, we are unfamiliar with the pure RPM operations, and `rpm -qa --last` seems to be tracking the existing packages only, not including the removed ones.

**Question:**
So, we started to doubt our knowledge of the `yum history` command, and hope to get pointers about how to find out the update history on specific RPM packages.

Please also point out if we missed anything, and we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The history is stored in `/var/lib/dnf/history*` files. And actually `history` option of `yum` show the commands which are executed. Try to run:

```
yum history
```

and you will see it. If the operation is not visible probably the package is installed via `rpm` and you have only the act it is installed or not.